# following a hyperlink inside div

Tags: jquery

I have several divs like this:

```
<div class="MenuList"><a class="SiteLink" href="page.aspx">My Link</a></div>
```

The problem is that if the user clicks on the div but not on the text, the link won't trigger. This is what I have so far:

```
    $('#TopMenuBar .MenuList').click(function () {
        //alert($(this).next('SiteLink').html());
    });
```

What I'd like to do is extract the link from the anchor and go to the page.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#TopMenuBar .MenuList').click(function () {
        $(this).children('a').click();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Hm, if the desired behaivior is to extend the "clickable" surface of the anchor, perhaps using css on the .Sitelink-class is a good idea (padding, margin etc). That way you would not have to use Javascript/jQuery in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

```
  $(document).bind("ready", function() {
      $('#TopMenuBar .MenuList a.SiteLink').click(function () {
          // do what you want to do here
      });
  });
```